# How to find the package referenced in the Android project

Tags: java, android

I want to build a project about menstrual records,so I used a third party open source libraries from github.This line I used in my own project but it is grey,so I think I lack of some package.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA6lm.png)

Comment: .R import is grayed?

Comment: yes，so I feel uncertain